# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-import

I finally had to post this here after, embarrassingly, being stuck for almost 2 days. I have been trying to import a file from a directory on same level as my parent directory. Here is my project structure:

```
website
├──pages
│  └──views.py
└──website
   └──urls.py
```

You can see a more detailed structure from the image attached. I am trying to import views.py in urls.py with:
from website.pages import views

This gives the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'website.pages'. I tried using relative import as well:
from ..pages import views
I got an error here as well:
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Please help!
[image: Code]

After renaming
[image: After renaming]

Answer (score 3):

This is because the name 'website' of your repository is the same as the name you call.

[image]

**To solve the problem:**

[image]

Comment: I changed it to web and got the error: No module named 'web'.

Comment: @lekarane Can you post the screenshot after you modified it?

Comment: @lekarane Try to use this： import web_dev.web.pages

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from your pic . You seems to have your project name as website and also your app name as website. Django firstly tries to find the module in your project and not in your app. To correct this you have to import using:

```
from pages import views
```

But still that is a bad practice to name your project and your app the same name. Plz change your top level directory name.

Comment: The lower "website" folder is the default configuration folder created by the command, django-admin startproject website. I tried renaming and the same error pops up.

Comment: You have to change the name of top level project directory. @lekarne

Comment: I changed the name of the top level project directory to "web", and got "No module named 'web' "

Comment: You don't have to use `from web.pages import xyz` instead use `from pages import xyz` @lekarane

Comment: That was the first way I tried it, and I just tried again. It is flagged as a syntax error

Comment: Have you added `pages` to installed apps in `settings.py`

Comment: I have added "pages" to installed apps in settings.py